# Making a Search Filter with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a Table made from some json data...

```
 {
 "AKH":{
 "name": "Amonkhet",
 "code": "AKH"
 "cards": [
{
  "artist": "Izzy",
    "cmc": 3,
    "colorIdentity": [
      "W"
    ],
    "colors": [
      "White"
    ],
    "id": "df3a6e0336684c901358f3ff53ec82ff5d7cdb9d",
    "imageName": "gideon of the trials",
    "layout": "normal",
    "loyalty": 3,
    "manaCost": "{1}{W}{W}",
    "multiverseid": 426716,
    "name": "Gideon of the Trials",
    "number": "14",
    "rarity": "Mythic Rare",
    "subtypes": [
      "Gideon"
    ],
    "text": "+1: Until your next turn, prevent all damage target permanent would deal.\n0: Until end of turn, Gideon of the Trials becomes a 4/4 Human Soldier creature with indestructible that's still a planeswalker. Prevent all damage that would be dealt to him this turn.\n0: You get an emblem with \"As long as you control a Gideon planeswalker, you can't lose the game and your opponents can't win the game.\"",
    "type": "Planeswalker — Gideon",
    "types": [
      "Planeswalker"
    ]
},
```

The Table row ends up looking like this for each of the cards. at the moment I only Attach the ID, Card name, and Mana Cost to each row

```
<td><a href="#" onclick="showInfo(this.id)" 
 id="df3a6e0336684c901358f3ff53ec82ff5d7cdb9d">Gideon of the Trials</a></td>
```

Now I want to search through these cards. (Keep in mind there are over 17,000 different cards that will be on this list) I can get it to find the things.. But I'm having several different issues... Either it finds them all but doesn't hide the rest of the list, or it hides the whole list and only displays one of the found cards.

So question A... What am I missing to make the search work correctly?

```
 $(document).on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', function() {
        var lis = $('.cardsRow')

        $('input[type=checkbox]').filter(':checked').each(function(){
                    filterKeyB = $(this).attr('id')
                    filterKeyA = $(this).attr('name')
                    $.each(json, function(setCode, setListing) {
                    $.each(setListing.cards,function(cardNum, cardListing){
                    var x = Object.keys(cardListing)
                    var y = Object.keys(cardListing).map(function (key){
                    return cardListing[key]


                 })
            for (i = 0; (i < x.length); i++) {
            if(x[i] === filterKeyA){
             if (y[i] instanceof Array){
              var holder = y[i]
               var valueArr =[]
             for(var k = 0; k < holder.length; k++){
              valueArr = holder.join('|').toLowerCase().split('|')
              var foundIt = valueArr.includes(filterKeyB)

        }
                }else{
                 var stringy = y[i]
                var stringyA= stringy.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, '')
               if (stringyA === filterKeyB){
                var foundIt = true


         } 
        } 
        if(foundIt === true){ 
        $winner = cardListing.name

        for (k = 0; (k < lis.length); k++){
           if (lis[k].innerText.indexOf($winner) != -1) {
            $(lis[k]).show()
           }
        }





  } 
  }
 }        
})
```

Question B... Since you are already here... Would it be better practice to attach the data that can be searched to the element itself? Maybe just the most searched (Like Name and Mana) and have more advanced queries go through the data again?

Comment: The first thing you could do is indent your code properly? Currently it is borderline unreadable.

Comment: For search filter, if you are interested,  you can use `lodash` library to filter data easily. https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#filter

Comment: I would say yes to Question B. Just curious, do you use any server side code in your application? Would be better and easier to search using ajax on your server

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why the code isn't working or even how it works, it looks like it references some functions that aren't defined in the sample. But I can share with you a really simple/intuitive way to filter stuff, I hope you find it useful.

Native filter method is so useful for what you're trying to do, it takes a callback that takes current element as an arg and returns true or false, if true, the element is included in the new array it produces.

But filter only takes one function, and you have many filters, so let's make a function that combines many filter Fns together into one fn, so you can pass them in all at once:

```
const combineFilters = (...fns) => val => fns.reduce((prev, curr) => prev || curr(val), false);
```

OK, how about storing the names of the filter functions as keys in an object so we can reference them using a string? That way we could give each checkbox an ID corresponding to the name of the filter function they are supposed to apply, and makes things really easy to implement (and read):

```
const filterFns = {
    startsWithG(card) {
        return card.name[0] === 'G';
    },
    //etc.
};
```

OK, time to get the IDs of all the checkboxes that are clicked, then map them into an array of functions.

```
const filters = $('input[type=checkbox]')
                  .filter(':checked')
                  .map((e, i) => $(i).attr('id'))
                  .get()
                  .map(fnName => filterFns[fnName])
```

(Assume the relevant data is stored in a var called...data.) We can use combineFilters combined with filters (array of Fns) to activate all of the relevant filters, then map the resulting array of matching objects into the HTML of your choosing.

```
const matches = data.cards
                    .filter(combineFilters(...filters))
                    .map(card => `<div>${card.name}</div>` );
```

Then time to update DOM with your matches!

As others have noted, if you need to do any more complicated filtering on objects or arrays, lodash library is your friend!